# How to wait till API response complete in a loop before move to the next iteration (angular)

Tags: angular

In a for loop, I want to wait till these two api call completes and do some other thing before going to the next iteration. But not sure how can I do that in my code?

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let study = data[i].Study;
  let w = new WGCNAData(data[i].DendroFile, data[i].CorFile);
  this.exprWGCNAData.set(study, w);

  // fetch images
  this.imgService.getWGCNAImgByPath(w.CorImgFile, "png").subscribe(
    data => {
      this.exprWGCNAData.get(study).CorImgBlob = data;
    }, error => {
      console.log("Failt to load cor img");
    }
  )
  this.imgService.getWGCNAImgByPath(w.DendroImgFile, "png").subscribe(
    data => {
      this.exprWGCNAData.get(study).DendroImgBlob = data;
    }, error => {
      console.log("Fail to load dendrogram image");
    }
  )

  //do something with the image blobs before move to the next iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the calls inside a async method and await each response, before going to the next iteration like this:

```js
async loadImages() {
    let allSuccessful = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let study = data[i].Study;
        let w = new WGCNAData(data[i].DendroFile, data[i].CorFile);
        this.exprWGCNAData.set(study, w);
        const wasSuccessful = await (firstValueFrom(this.fetchImages(w, study));
        if (wasSuccessful) {
            // Do something...
        } else {
            // Do something else...
        }
        allSuccessful = allSuccessful && wasSuccessful;
    }
    return allSuccessful;
}


fetchImages(w: YourType, study: Study) {
    return forkJoin([
        this.imgService.getWGCNAImgByPath(w.CorImgFile, "png"),
        this.imgService.getWGCNAImgByPath(w.DendroImgFile, "png")])
        .pipe(
            tap([corImgBlob, dendroImgBlob] => {
                this.exprWGCNAData.get(study).CorImgBlob = corImgBlob;
                this.exprWGCNAData.get(study).DendroImgBlob = dendroImgBlob;
            }),
            map(() => true)
            catchError((error) => { 
                console.log(error)
                of(false))
            }
}
```

Now you can use the loadImages method as an Observable too:

```js
const imageLoader = from(this.loadImages);
imageLoader.subscribe((successful) => console.log(successful));
```

You can also try to use the retryWhen operator:
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention this is in a loop. Have updated the question.

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if this is what you need!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to write this code reactively.
Each HTTP call returns an Observable that emits the returned value when it completes.
One approach could be to use an RxJS operator to combine them into a single Observable.

For example:

```
const corImgFile$ = this.imgService.getWGCNAImgByPath(w.CorImgFile, "png");
const dendroImgFile$ = this.imgService.getWGCNAImgByPath(w.DendroImgFile, "png");

forkJoin([corImgFile$, dendroImgFile$])
.subscribe(([corImgFile, dendroImgFile]) => {
  console.log(`the returned values are ${corImgFile} and ${dendroImgFile}`)
});
```

[`.forkJoin()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) emits once after both have returned. [`.combineLatest()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) may be another solid choice.

Here is the RxJS documentation for operators: https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forget to add more details: the fetch images happens in a for loop..... My bad. I will update my question